# How to remove "div classes" after successful post-get method

Tags: javascript, html, css, post, shopify

On the contact-page there is an option, to send me a direct message via a form it gets redirected to my personal hotmail account, if the message is successful. There comes an message displaying in green text and a border and some padding that the message has been send;

But I simply want to remove some "div" classes because it doesn't look neat enough. But also bring back the "div" classes when the user goes to another page or refresh or when the statement is not "true" anymore.

And when a user submits the forum and enters his email address; that a no-reply mail gets sent to the user with some personal text etc. This is suppose to be simple; like a mailto: option, but I have no idea how to implement this directly and where.

Help would be really appreciated!

I've tried editing the .CSS success lines, but they don't work at all, same with the display: block attributes and other examples, the code got broken a lot of times, because I tried plenty but without any outcome, it is all .liquid code from shopify I can add everything that's needed to resolve this quickly.

Also tried with element and then reproduce this with html/css and Javascript but it simply messes up the entire display of the page.

page.contact.liquid: code

```
 {%- assign formId = 'ContactForm' -%}
 {% form 'contact', id: formId %}
 {% include 'form-status', form_id: formId %}

 <div class="grid grid--half-gutters">
 <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half">
 <label for="{{ formId }}-name">{{ 'contact.form.name' | t }}</label>
              <input type="text" id="{{ formId }}-name" name="contact[name]" value="{% if form[name] %}{{ form[name] }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.name }}{% endif %}">
            </div>
            <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half">
              <label for="{{ formId }}-email">{{ 'contact.form.email' | t }} <span aria-hidden="true">*</span></label>
              <input
                type="email"
                id="{{ formId }}-email"
                name="contact[email]"
                autocorrect="off"
                autocapitalize="off"
                value="{% if form.email %}{{ form.email }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.email }}{% endif %}"
                aria-required="true"
                {%- if form.errors contains 'email' -%}
                  class="input--error"
                  aria-invalid="true"
                  aria-describedby="{{ formId }}-email-error"
                {%- endif -%}
                >
              {%- if form.errors contains 'email' -%}
                <span id="{{ formId}}-email-error" class="input-error-message">{% include 'icon-error' %} {{ form.errors.translated_fields['email'] | capitalize }} {{ form.errors.messages['email'] }}.</span>
              {%- endif -%}
            </div>
          </div>

          <label for="{{ formId }}-message">{{ 'contact.form.message' | t }}</label>
          <textarea rows="10" id="{{ formId }}-message" name="contact[body]">{% if form.body %}{{ form.body }}{% endif %}</textarea>

          <input type="reset" class="btn" value="{{ 'contact.form.reset' | t }}">
          <input type="submit" class="btn" value="{{ 'contact.form.submit' | t }}">

        {% endform %}
      </div>
```

form-status.liquid this is the #include code;

```
{%- if form.posted_successfully? -%}
  <p class="form-message form-message--success" tabindex="-1" data-form-status>
    {{ success_message | default: 'contact.form.post_success' | t }}
  </p>
{%- endif -%}
```

The .CSS code

```
.note,
.form-message {
  padding: $input-padding-top-bottom-small;
  margin: 0 0 ($gutter-site / 2);

  @include media-query($medium-up) {
    padding: $input-padding-top-bottom;
  }
}

.note {
  border: 1px solid $color-border-form;
}

.form-message--success {
  border: 1px solid $color-success;
  background-color: $color-success-bg;
  color: $color-success;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The "div" classes that needs to be removed and reappear when the statement is not "true" anymore or when the user clicks on another page/refresh option.

`<div class="rte">`

```
<div class="contact-form form-vertical"><form method="post" action="/contact#ContactForm" id="ContactForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="contact-form"><input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="contact"><input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓">
```

HTML that gets in the contact page when the user submitted his message successfully;

```
<p class="form-message form-message--success" data-form-status="">
    Bedankt dat je contact met ons hebt opgenomen. We nemen zo snel mogelijk contact met je op. 
  </p>
```

Comment: Whats wrong with `$(element).show()` and `$(element).hide()`

Comment: And as far as emails go, that should be its own question.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear and also it seems you do not have the required knowledge to do such things. Anyway. If you want to remove/add classes when something happens you have to do that in js. Find where the form is submitted and on success add the class. If you want to just override the styles of `.form-message--success` you can do that by [overriding the styles you want in CSS](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/responsive-web-design/basic-css/override-styles-in-subsequent-css/).

Comment: I've managed to get it somehow to work, but it only works when an user clicks on the div, after the message has been successful, it needs to be like loaded automatically, researched all the possible options on the JavaScript events; but not sure which one has the right behaviour; 
        ```document.getElementById("rte").onclick = function() { 
  
            document.getElementById("rte").style.display = "none"; 
  
        } 
```

Comment: I've successfully fixed it myself. Please close this thread.